# List of strings to DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

This is my model:

```
public class ContentPage
    {

        public BlogPost BlogPost { get; set; }
        public List<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }

        public List<string> Kategorier { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to use the values in the

```
public List<string> Kategorier { get; set; }
```

In a dropdownlistfor, this is what i got so far:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.BlogPost.Kategori, "Here i want my list i guess?"(o => new SelectListItem { Text = o.Kategori, Value = o.Kategori }), "", null)
```

To clearify, I want to use the values in the List Kategorier in order to set the value for the o.BlogPost.Kategori
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a number of overloads you can use, but the one I find most readable is

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BlogPost.Kategori, 
                               Model.Kategorier.Select(kat => new SelectListItem { Text = kat, Value = kat })
```

Part of the reason why I like this overload is just that I prefer strong typing and being helped by the (aspnet) compiler. I generally avoid `SelectList` and its `string`-based constructors because they are brittle.

You may want to turn your `List<string>` into an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in your view model instead of having to do it in the view.

**EDIT:**

I would do something like

```
public class ContentPage
{
    public ContentPage(){} //Default constructor needed for model binding
    public ContentPage(List<string> kategorier /* and possibly more arguments */)
    {
        Kategorier = kategorier.Select(k => new SelectListItem { Text = k, Value = k });
    }

    public BlogPost BlogPost { get; set; }
    public List<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Kategorier { get; set; }
}
```

Be aware that this should be fine for creating new blogposts, but if you want to edit existing blog posts, you will have to do a little more work (categories will have to be selected etc. when you render the page initially etc).

Comment: That did exactly what I wanted! 
Out of interest, if I changed my List<string> to an IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, the how would the DropDownList look in the view? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "how would the DropDownList look"? Are you referring to source code or to how it would look visually in a browser (or something else entirely)?

Comment: I as refering to the source-code and how it would differ from the one in your answer.